# Can fbevents.js override Google Analytics event tracking?

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-analytics

I'm responsible for a department website for a university (https://www.unomaha.edu/college-of-business-administration/economics/).  Because this is driven by a CMS, I can control a portion of the body section.  However, the sausage code in the header or in the bottom portion of the body, I have no way to remove.

In the header of the page, the university has loaded Google Tag Manager.  What I'd like to is record some in-page events using the standard Google Analytics approach.  However, when these events are fired, (a) the event isn't recorded in Google Analytics and (b) if you have the Google Developer Console open there is a call to https://www.facebook.com/tr/.

I've tried this using both the dataLayer push method and a direct call to the "ga" function. Both result in no event recorded and a call to facebook.  Directly looking at the dataLayer array in the console does show the event was pushed to the array.

gtag method (gtag defined earlier in the code):

```
gtag('event', 'econ_passion', {
    'event_category': 'econ_passion',
    'event_label': passion,
    'event_action': 'open_passion'
});
```

ga method:

```
ga('send', {
     hitType: 'event',
     eventCategory: 'econ_passion',
     eventAction: 'open_passion',
     eventLabel: passion
});
```

What seems to be happening is that fbevents is dynamically loaded into the bottom portion of the body tag.

Has someone experienced this?  Understanding that I can't actually remove the facebook code, is there a way you've found around this problem such that I can record G. analytics events?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong methods to push the event to GTM then GA. To track an event through GA implemented through GTM, you need to have access to the GTM container as well.

Comment: Could you expand on your answer?  This method seems to be the standard method (see https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide).  It is of note that that the gtag function is defined above as ```function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}```

Comment: gtag.js and GTM are two different methods of implementing GA. if you use gtag() then you have to use gtag.js, if you use dataLayer.push() then you're going to be using GTM. I don't see where you got function `gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}`